# 3d objects in binary files

Tags: java, 3d, file, jogl, binary

Currently I have 11 3d spheres created at runtime in my application. The application runs well as it is, but I'm anticipating some garbage collection hiccups due to camera panning.  Would  performance increase if the objects were written, then read the objects from a binary file?

Comment: Performance of what exactly? Reading a 3d object data (not likely)? Rendering it on screen(not at all)? Interchanging 3d objects(probably not noticeably)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about performance, there's no reason to add additional operations to your setup. Especially operations containing hard disk read/writes as those are some of the slowest operations you can perform.

Additionally, since it's running fine now, there's nothing to fix yet. You should start worrying about performance, when there's a performance issue. Situations like this can easily be retrofitted later; there's no major code overhaul involved. Though, if performance does become an issue with this scenario in the future, I'd expect other optimizations to be more effective than reading from a binary file.

However, the best answer you can get for this, is the one you provide yourself. Profile both scenarios, and with empirical evidence you can prove to yourself which one is faster.